# Automatically delete older version of Visual Studio Code on Windows

Tags: windows, text-editor, visual-studio-code

Microsoft recently launched [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (or VSCode for short) — a cross-platform code editor. I have noticed something that annoys me a lot. When Visual Studio Code updates on Windows, the old version is still in your hard drive and it is not auto-deleted.

How can I have all older versions to be auto-deleted instead of doing it manually?

Comment: This might be a good SO question, especially if there would turn up some preference, setting, or knob in the installer to do this. It might also be either a bug or a feature of (the installer for) VSCode, so I'd suggest also reporting it as such to Microsoft, and get back to us here should they have an answer.

Comment: The same for Mac. If I right-click on a file and select `open with` I can choose 3 different versions so far `v1.6.1`, `v1.8.1` and `v1.9.0`.

Answer (score -3):

The update framework that we are using (Squirrel) takes care of deleting older releases over time, you don't have to worry about it!

Comment: Can you go into more detail? Who is "we" and how does it decide to delete old releases?

Comment: I think Squirrel keeps the N-1 content and deletes anything N-2 from the current release. The motivation is likely that you can go back at least 1 version if needed. We are not exposing this option though.

Comment: When Visual studio code updates the entries in the registry still point to the older version so when you right click to open file using visual studio code it is not able to find the latest version of visual studio code.